# AndroidStudio - replace all occurences in erroneous lines only

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

What I want is following:

*Search through every exception and replace any occurence of "A" with "B" but only in the lines with exceptions.*

This is something that must be done after library upgrades as soon as a function is replaced with a new one and the old one is removed instead of deprecated for example.

Any trick to do that?

**Example**

- I replace all occurences of `.getId()` with `.getRowId()` (because my annotation processor for all my database classes changed and removed the `getId()` function with a `getRowId()` function instead)
- now I want to replace all occurences of `.getRowId()` that throw errors with `.getId()` again

Comment: Please provide a sample input and output for your question!

Comment: the question is quite simple, I don't think that's necessary, but I do it... it's not specific to the in- and output, it's just a very gerneral question about the IDE and if it supports something like this (independent of a use case, I would think this is useful in other cases as well)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reach Replace in Path menu. Use **Ctrl + Shift + R** shortcut or find it from menu **Edit > Find > Replace in Path** - [[source](http://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/find-and-replace-in-path.html)]